# Having an error while displaying the image from an API in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am having an error and am unable to fetch the image from the API and they are showing me an error although it works on img tag but when i replace the this with NextJS Image tag then it is showing me this error.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import Image from 'next/image';
    
    const ChannelDetailCard = ({
      data,
      id,
      channel_image,
      channel_name,
    
    }) => {
    
      return (
        <>
            <div className="ml-0 flex justify-center lg:flex lg:ml-10">
              <Image
                className="w-64 h-64 object-cover rounded"
                src={channel_image}
                objectFit="contain"
                layout='fill'
              />
           </div>  
         </> 
             ) 
     }
    }
```

Here is the Error which i gets while running this code.(Sample)
[image]

Comment: but where is the error !!!

Comment: I have updated my post please review it

Comment: Looks like ``channel_image`` is empty or doesn't contain a value. Check for that!

Comment: Actually it contains a value and previously i am using <img> tag it works perfectly fines in it but when i replaced it with Next JS own Image Tag then it is showing me this error

Comment: any sample (example) value that the ``channel_image`` holds?

Comment: I have updated my post please check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247363/discussion-between-wasiq-ali-and-omi-shah).

Comment: Looks to me like the returned URL has a whitespace in it. Was there supposed to be an underscore or something? Have you tried logging the returned URL in the console?

Comment: Oh, I do see your console log. It does appear to have a space, which would make the URL invalid, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you're loading images from external source, different domain than the current application domain, you need to explicitly add all the domains of the images that you're loading in the `next.config.js` file as mentioned [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host)

Edit your `next.config.js` file and add:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['example.domain.com'],
  },
}
```

Make sure to replace `example.domain.com` with the domain name of your image source. After saving reload and it should work.

Comment: Thankyou now it works fine by adding the above line

Answer (score 1):

in your nextjs config

```
u have to add the hostename of the website u bring images from
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: true,
swcMinify: true,
images: {
domains: ["********.com"],
},
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

---

if u have multiple origins, then u have to add them like this
domains:["abc.com","xyz.com"]

Comment: please avoid commenting as an answer !!!

Comment: i dont know all the rules here, but i gave a possible solution to the problem.

Comment: I have updated my post please check it

Comment: are you sure all channel_image comes always with data? or some card doesnt have an src?

Comment: Yes it always comes up with image data, I am getting this error when I am using NextJS image tag otherwise it is working fine in <img> tag

Comment: in your nextjs config, add images: {
    domains: ["hostname"],
  } with hostname is the website url u bring from it the images

Comment: Thank you, Now it is working fine when I have added the above line in the config file.